# Inconsistent data types

Tags: oracle

```
select SAMPLE_LOT_ID 
from etldm.SAMPLE_LOT
where  dbms_lob(GRIEVANCE_IDS)="786";
```

I m trying this code but getting below error:

> ORACLE prepare error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB.

Here is an SQL statement:

```
SELECT  "SAMPLE_LOT_ID", "GRIEVANCE_IDS" 
FROM etldm.SAMPLE_LOT  
WHERE  ("GRIEVANCE_IDS" = '786' )
```

.

Comment: Try to cast your [clob to a varchar](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::no::p11_question_id:367980988799) before checking for equality. Out of curiosity: why do you store IDs as CLOBS?

Comment: I am doing this in SAS creating a macro for ID . New in oracle so can you pls tell me what does error mean and what's the exact code? @krunal

Comment: I am not 100% sure, which is why I posted this as a comment, but the error message says that you are getting a CLOB, which means "Character Large Object" and is a data type you use when storing huge amounts of character data that would not fit into normal data types like VARCHAR. To compare a CLOB with characters like you do it first needs to be cast to a VARCHAR, so you take the first 4,000 characters from the CLOB and then do the comparison. dbms_lob.substr( GRIEVANCE_IDS, 4000, 0 ) = '786'; might do the trick.

Comment: @Secespitus: tried this but getting syntax error
Syntax error, expecting one of the following: IN, NOTIN.

Comment: I don't have access to a database to test this right now. The tutorial mentioned 1 instead of 0 as the third argument. Other than that you syntax error tells you that he is expecting a WHERE-Clause that uses IN for a range. BTW: In your second example you don't need the brackets and by putting everything in parentheses you are not accessing the data, only the strings in the parentheses. Try: SELECT  SAMPLE_LOT_ID, GRIEVANCE_IDS FROM etldm.SAMPLE_LOT  WHERE  dbms_lob.substr( GRIEVANCE_IDS, 3, 1 ) = '786'